# Matlab - elmination of rows in array that is not needed

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, rows

I am comparing a 100 x 1 called "x" with the value from a 4 x 1 matrix called "xCP". I need a finalMatrix with only the values in x that are higher than the third value from xCP. However, the code i have below provides me with a 100 x 1 matrix with zeros in rows that the value are not higher. I only want the 25(e.g.) rows in finalMatrix that have the higher value. So my finalMatrix needs to be a 25 x 1 with values instead of 100 x 1 with 25 values and 75 zeros.

This is what i have so far:

```
K = size (x)
length = K(1)
finalMatrix = zeros(length,1);

count = 1;
for i=1:length;
    if x(count,1) >= xCP(3)
    finalMatrix(count,1) = x(count,1);
    end
    count =count+1;
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: `finalMatrix = x(x>xCP(3))`? The main idea is to index into `x` with that logical array of ones and zeros that you had, thus using `logical indexing`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `finalMatrix(count+1:length,1) = []` in the end of the code.  It will remove the excess elements.

Comment: Can you please explain that line of code? I want to be clear so that i would remember how to do it in the future.

Comment: The `[]` idiom is a very popular one in MATLAB.  When you do `[]` it is going to **remove** elements that are specified by your matrix / vector indexing.  For example, if you did `x = 1:10;`, then did `x(1:4) = [];`, the first statement creates an array of 10 elements enumerated from 1-10. The second statement will physically **remove** the first four elements from `x`.  As such, should you examine `x` again, you will only see that the array has elements from 5-10. This will have **six** elements in `x` as opposed to having 10 earlier.

Comment: Understood. Thank you rayryeng and ja72